# How do I make the x potion in my cauldron?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do I brew the x potion? I can not figure out the right recipe.

Comment: @5pike no duplicate, because this is "candy-box 2", not "the gold factory"!

Comment: @SimeKappa - Oh damn, you are right.

Comment: @5pike I think you just picked the wrong question :D

Comment: @Kodama you're right!

Answer (score 1):

The following comes from the [Candy Box 2 Wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/X_Potion):

> 1. Put a candy in your cauldron.
> 2. Heat up until the water is cold, then stop.
> 3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 three more times, so at the end there are a total of 4 candies in the pot.
> 4. Put a lollipop in your cauldron.
> 5. Heat up until the water is "hot", then stop.
> 6. Put into bottles.